# MKMapView Not being called Swift ios 8

Tags: xcode, swift, ios8, mkmapview

Hi im just wondering why isnt my MapView function is not being called. I am trying to draw a line between points but all is showing is just the center location. 
Thanks in advance. 
    import UIKit
import CoreLocation
import MapKit

class ThirdViewController: UIViewController , CLLocationManagerDelegate {

```
@IBOutlet weak var theMap: MKMapView!

@IBOutlet weak var theLabel: UILabel!

    var manager:CLLocationManager!
    var myLocations: [CLLocation] = []

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        //Setup our Location Manager
        manager = CLLocationManager()
        self.manager.delegate = self
        manager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
        manager.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        manager.startUpdatingLocation()


        //Setup our Map View
       // theMap.delegate = self
        theMap.mapType = MKMapType.Standard
        theMap.showsUserLocation = true
    }


    func locationManager(manager:CLLocationManager, didUpdateLocations locations:[AnyObject]) {
        theLabel.text = "\(locations[0])"
        myLocations.append(locations[0] as CLLocation)

        let spanX = 0.007
        let spanY = 0.007
        var newRegion = MKCoordinateRegion(center: theMap.userLocation.coordinate, span: MKCoordinateSpanMake(spanX, spanY))
        theMap.setRegion(newRegion, animated: true)
        println("not yet ")
        if (myLocations.count > 1){
            println("here ")
            var sourceIndex = myLocations.count - 1
            var destinationIndex = myLocations.count - 2
            let c1 = myLocations[sourceIndex].coordinate
            let c2 = myLocations[destinationIndex].coordinate
            var a = [c1, c2]
            var polyline = MKPolyline(coordinates: &a, count: a.count)
            theMap.addOverlay(polyline)
        }
}
func mapView(mapView: MKMapView!, rendererForOverlay overlay: MKOverlay!) -> MKOverlayRenderer! {
    println("sad")
    if overlay is MKPolyline {
        println("aadsfsad")
        var polylineRenderer = MKPolylineRenderer(overlay: overlay)
        polylineRenderer.strokeColor = UIColor.blueColor()
        polylineRenderer.lineWidth = 4
        return polylineRenderer
    }
    return nil
}
```

}

Comment: Is it because that you are checking myLocations > 1. Should it be myLocations > 0.

Comment: if i change that to 0 then i get a array out of index error

Comment: So i figured it out. I did not self the map delegate to self. So theMap.delegate = self in the view did load thats why the overlay did not appear.

Answer (score 0):

in ios8+ MapView didn`t load LocationCoordinate automatically. If we want to use MKMapView to load the more accurate location with "mapView:didUpdateUserLocation":

**Premise:** 

1.setup the mapView delegate. 

2.setShowsUserLocation:YES 

3.mapView must in a container(addSubview:mapView)!!!!!

For example:

```
self.mapView = [[MKMapView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 1, 1)];
_mapView.delegate = self;
[_mapView setShowsUserLocation:YES];
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:_mapView];
```

Comment: Hello. This question was tagged "swift": please provide your code in Swift. Thank you.